# Test file word cloud in F#

Tags: recursion, f#

This code is meant to take in a command line argument and output a 'tag cloud'. It's more of an exercise in learning F# for me because this is my first non-tutorial code file. How could this code be improved?

```
open System.IO
open System
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args = 

    let directory = args.[0]

    let fileNames = Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, "*Tests.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories) |> Seq.toList

    let allLines = List.collect(fun (x:string) -> System.IO.File.ReadLines(x) |> Seq.toList) fileNames

    let allWords = List.collect(fun (x:string) -> x.Split([|' ';'_';';';':';'(';')';'\\';'/';'>';'<';'{';'}';'0';'1';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'.'|], StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) |> Seq.toList) allLines
    //printfn "%A" allWords

    let countOccurance (word:string) list = 
        let count = List.filter (fun x -> word.Equals(x)) list
        (word, count.Length)

    let distinctWords = allWords |> Seq.distinct |> Seq.toList

    let print (tup:string*int) =
        match tup with
        | (a,b) -> printfn "%A: %A" a b

    let rec wordCloud distinct (all:string list) (acc:(string*int) list) =
        match distinct with
        | [] -> acc
        | head :: tail -> 
            let accumSoFar = acc @ [(countOccurance head all)]
            wordCloud tail all accumSoFar

    let acc = []
    let cloud = (wordCloud distinctWords allWords acc)

    let rec printTup (tupList:(string*int) list) =
        match tupList with
        | [] -> 0
        | head :: tail -> 
            printfn "%A" head
            printTup tail

    printTup cloud

    0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*inb4 Scott* :-)

Use functions more. Composability is not very important in this example, but it's good to get into that habit early on.

In that spirit, turn the non-trivial value bindings into functions instead of closing over a previously defined value. Also try turning the non-trivial lambda expressions into functions; that gives them a name and makes the call site more readable.

Also, pipe more. :-) Especially for the list/sequence functions that take a higher order function, it's more readable to pipe the list into them, because it makes it more obvious what you're starting from.

Also, in my experience, defining "constant" values and functions first before actually doing any work makes the code much easier to follow, because you don't have to think about what values you already "have" at which point.

Oh, and while tail recursion is a very cool thing to have, it's not very useful here and actually makes the code quite a bit less understandable.

Did you put the type annotations in on purpose? In most cases, you don't need them because of F#'s powerful type inference. They can sometimes make code more easy to follow, but they might also constrain it where it could actually be more generic, and in general not having to specify types all the time is one of the really nice things about F#. :-)

**Edit:** Reading this again made me think of another important point: The individual function declarations don't belong in the `main` function; moving them out of there makes the distinction between "parts" and the actual "running" program even clearer.

With these things taken into consideration, your code could look like this:

```
open System
open System.IO

// It's a tiny bit more maintainable to keep this list separate, and makes it more readable where it is used
let separators = [|' ';'_';';';':';'(';')';'\\';'/';'>';'<';'{';'}';'0';'1';'2';'3';'4';'5';'6';'7';'8';'9';'.'|]
let fileNamePattern = "*Tests.cs"

// Function with the directory and pattern as a parameter
let getFileNames fileNamePattern directory =
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory, fileNamePattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    |> Seq.toList

// Function with the list of filenames as a parameter
let getAllLines fileNames = fileNames |> List.collect (System.IO.File.ReadLines >> Seq.toList)

// Function with the list of lines as a parameter
let getAllWords lines =
    lines
    |> List.collect (fun (line : string) ->
        line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        |> Seq.toList)

// Reordered parameters for pipeability
let countOccurrences allWords word =
    // The = operator can be used as a function that takes two arguments.
    let count = allWords |> List.filter ((=) word) |> List.length
    word, count

// Function that takes a sequence of "anything" and returns a list of the distinct values
let distinctWords = Seq.distinct >> Seq.toList

// F# string formatting is strongly typed and compiler checked; take advantage of that, don't just use %A
let printWordCount (word, count) = printfn "%s: %i" word count

// Now that everything is "set up", we can "run" with the current data:
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    // This binding isn't really necessary, but it's nice to give the value a name
    let directory = args.[0]

    // We now have a clear execution path that is very easy to follow
    let allWords =
        directory
        |> getFileNames fileNamePattern
        |> getAllLines
        |> getAllWords

    let distinct = distinctWords allWords

    distinct
    |> List.map (countOccurrences allWords)
    |> List.iter printWordCount

    0
```

Comment: A lot of my difficulties with F# so far have been with type inference and things becoming arrays when I think they are lists and so on, which is why I was annotating params so often. This code is much clearer, wow! I need to really sit down and get a feel for it.

Comment: I see; using type annotations is a good strategy then for verifying your understanding and expectations, yes.

Comment: I realized the function declarations don't actually belong inside the `main` method (they could really live "anywhere"); I have updated the code accordingly.